# Video capture software for app demo

Tags: video

Many years ago, there used to be a very popular software often used to video record app user experience, with a yellow disc briefly showing up anywhere you click. I liked it because it made obvious all clicks.

Any idea what it was and whether it still exists today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of screen cast tools nowadays animate mouse clicks, often configurable, personally I like [ActivePresenter](https://atomisystems.com/activepresenter/) for its intuitive user interface.